# The $\delta$ notation in Goldstein's Classical Mechanics on the calculus of variation

Tags: classical-mechanics, notation, action, calculus, variational-calculus

In Goldstein's classical mechanics (page 36) he introduces the basics of the calculus of variation and uses it to effectively the Euler-Lagrange equations. However, there is a step in which the $\delta$ notation is defined:

$$\delta y\equiv \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha}\right)\text d\alpha,$$

in which $\alpha$ is the parameter used in the path modification:

$$y(\alpha,x)=y(0,x)+\alpha\eta(x),$$

$x$ is effectively a generalised time parameter. Both of these definitions are fine, however this notation is then introduced into the action integral:

$$\frac{\text dJ}{\text d\alpha}=\int^{x_2}_{x_1}\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{\text d}{\text dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot y}\right)\frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha}\text dx,$$

which becomes:

$$\delta J=\int^{x_2}_{x_1}\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{\text d}{\text dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot y}\right)\delta y\text dx,$$

which seems to imply that:

$$\delta y\stackrel{?}{\equiv}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha}\right)\neq \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha}\right)\text d\alpha.$$

I can see that (maybe a little hand-wavingly) this corresponds to a multiplication by $\text d\alpha/\text d\alpha$, but I'm not sure if that's a valid way to think of it. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\delta J\equiv d\alpha\frac{\partial J}{\partial \alpha}=d\alpha\int_{x_1}^{x_2}(\cdots)\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}dx=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}(\cdots)\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}d\alpha\right) dx\equiv \int_{x_1}^{x_2}(\cdots)\delta y dx$$

Comment: So $\text d\alpha$ can be brought inside the integral? Is this a general property?

Comment: @Charlie $d\alpha$ represents infinitesimal departure and as such is to be manipulated as number. For well behaved integrals and functions, there is no problem taking it inside as our intuition should be correct. It is then up to mathematicians to give precise meaning to this weird $d\alpha$ and to formulate what "well behaved" means. I do not know this math so rigorously though.

Comment: Ok that's fine, this answers my question, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Using $\delta J = \frac{\text dJ}{\text d\alpha} \mathrm{d}\alpha$, we see that:

$$\delta J = \int^{x_2}_{x_1}\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{\text d}{\text dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha} \mathrm{d}\alpha \right) \mathrm{d}x $$

Invoking the definition of $\delta y$ arrives at the expected result.